# Powershell: How can I avoid counting enters (blanked line) of output from a command?

Tags: powershell, measure-object

This is my code to count lines, I only have 69 lines which has a value on each line:

```
Get-AppPackage | Select-Object -Property name, publisherid | Measure-Object -Property name -line
```

Output:

```
Lines Words Characters Property
----- ----- ---------- --------
   71                  Name
```

But it's counting enters as well which I don't need them.

Help?

Comment: I might be missing something,. but if you just want to know how many items are returned you can do this: ```(Get-AppPackage | Measure-Object).Count```, or ```@(Get-AppPackage).Length```. If they give ```71``` as well, chances are you've miscounted and there's not ```69``` :-).

Comment: Im guessing you're looking for `Get-AppPackage | ? Name | Measure...`

Comment: @mclayton `Measure-Object`  is counting header and 1 line(without any value, looks it presses enter )  at the end which I don't want them. although it shows 71 lines but there are only 69 lines which has a value

Comment: what value are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the helpful comments:

> This is my code to count lines

Your code doesn't count *lines*.
It counts the number of `.Name` property values whose *stringified representation* results in *non-empty strings*, because you're combining [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object)'s 
`-Line` switch with (non-string) *object* input and a `-Property` argument.

- If you want to count the *number of objects* (AppX packages):

```bash
(Get-AppPackage).Count
```

- If you wanted to count the number of objects (AppX packages) *whose `.Name` property contains neither the empty string nor `$null`*, use the following - but note that this should be true of *all* objects returned by `Get-AppPackage`:

```bash
(Get-AppPackage | Where-Object Name).Count
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @BEHXAD.